# How to remove all children in HtmlElement with Silverlight/C#

Tags: c#, html, silverlight

So I have this Silverlight application that calls some reports(.rdlc) via **HTML form submit**.
This form is universal, so I use it to call all reports with it.

Now I want to clear the input elements in it everytime the form has been submited.

So I want a **clear form** everytime I want to call a new report with **no children** in it.

Can anyone explain why this is not working when there are more than 5(or any larger amount of inputs) inputs in the form?

```
    public static void RemoveInputsFromForm(HtmlElement Form)
    {
        if (HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById(Form.Id) != null)
        {
            foreach (HtmlElement element in Form.Children)
            {
                if (element.Id != string.Empty)
                {
                    element.Parent.RemoveChild(element);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The form has it's ID and every input has an ID, it **removes** some inputs randomly, others **stay** in the form.

This is the method that inserts the input elements into that form:

```
public static void AddInputToForm(HtmlElement Form, string Name, object Data)
    {
        if (Data != null && Data.ToString() != string.Empty)
        {
            var input = HtmlPage.Document.CreateElement("input");
            input.SetProperty("type", "hidden");
            input.SetProperty("value", Data.ToString());
            input.SetProperty("name", Name);
            input.SetProperty("id", Name);
            Form.AppendChild(input);
        }
    }
```

This is the method that I use now to remove form children, it is the same as `AddInputToForm` method only that it removes inputs

```
 public static void RemoveInputFromForm(HtmlElement Form, string Name)
    {

        if (HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById(Name) != null)
        {
            Form.RemoveChild(HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById(Name));
        }

    }
```

This is the method that gets my form

```
  public static HtmlElement GetForm(string formUrl)
    {
        //in the html that holds the silverlight object, you must have a form named "reportform"
        //<form id="reportform" action="" method="post" target="_blank" style="visibility: collapse" />
        HtmlElement functionReturnValue = null;


        //set form
        functionReturnValue = HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("reportform");

        //set form action
        functionReturnValue.SetProperty("action", formUrl);


        return functionReturnValue;
    }
```

To reproduce the code (SomeElement is an object with string properties):

```
           //get form
            var Form = GetForm(ApplicationUrl + @"Reports\Report.aspx");

            //add parameters to form
            AddInputToForm(Form, "id1", SomeElement.Id1Value);
            AddInputToForm(Form, "id2", SomeElement.Id2Value);
            AddInputToForm(Form, "id3", SomeElement.Id3Value);
            AddInputToForm(Form, "id4", SomeElement.Id4Value);
            AddInputToForm(Form, "id5", SomeElement.Id5Value);
            AddInputToForm(Form, "id6", SomeElement.Id6Value);
            AddInputToForm(Form, "id7", SomeElement.Id7Value);
            AddInputToForm(Form, "id8", SomeElement.Id8Value);
            AddInputToForm(Form, "id9", SomeElement.Id9Value);

            //submit form
            Form.Invoke("submit");

            //clean report
            RemoveInputFromForm(Form, "id1");
            RemoveInputFromForm(Form, "id2");
            RemoveInputFromForm(Form, "id3");
            RemoveInputFromForm(Form, "id4");
            RemoveInputFromForm(Form, "id5");
            RemoveInputFromForm(Form, "id6");
            RemoveInputFromForm(Form, "id7");
            RemoveInputFromForm(Form, "id8");
            RemoveInputFromForm(Form, "id9");
```

So you see I have to remove every child I added with as many calls as there are inputs in the form, I would like to have only **one call and clean that form**.

*Thanks in advance to any given solution.*

Comment: So you have a Silverlight app that dynamically builds an HTML form to retrieve your RDLC report? Sounds cool, I would love to see a sample.

Comment: All the code you need is in this post, you just have to read the request parameters on the aspx page that holds the .rdlc file. I do serialize the object and deserialize it in the aspx page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never add or remove elements while inside a `foreach` loop, as the collection changes and invalidates the loop. Rather add all items to be removed in a separate list and then remove them in a second loop. (I haven't tested it because I do not have relevant sample code, but this is a common mistake with `foreach` loops.)

```
List<HtmlElement> toRemove = new List<HtmlElement>();
foreach (HtmlElement element in Form.Children)
{
    if (element.Id != string.Empty)
    {
        toRemove.Add(element);
    }
}
foreach (HtmlElement element in toRemove)
{
    Form.RemoveChild(element);
}
```

Alternatively, using your second approach, you can always add all your IDs to a list, and then add a `RemoveAllFormInputs()` method which loops over these elements.

Answer (score 0):

Peet has provided the correct answer, however some may prefer a Linq based approach that slims the code a litte.

```
foreach (HtmlElement element in Form.Children
                                    .OfType<HtmlElement>
                                    .Where(e => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Id))
                                    .ToList() )
{
    Form.RemoveChild(element);
}
```