# window without parameters

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, url, parameters

How can I pass parameters from silverlight(xaml page) to an aspx page without showing them on url link?

if I do this:

```
HtmlWindow hw = System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.PopupWindow(new Uri(path), "rptapp", options);
```

it will pass my parameters but they will appear in url.

I don't want to encrypt them...I just them not to appear there

Comment: if your aspx page shares Session with your Silverlight page, you could try using Session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a form in your page where you host the XAP file of your silverlight application and submit the form to the new url with the post method.

you fill the action attribute with your link and add input elements to it:

```
<form id="popupform" action="" method="post" target="_blank" style="visibility: collapse" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
```

Read more here: [How to remove all children in HtmlElement with Silverlight/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744457/how-to-remove-all-children-in-htmlelement-with-silverlight-c)